# Alerta ao clicar em botões

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe possibilidade de simplificar este código? Algo me diz que sim. Quero que apareça um alerta diferente após clicar em cada botão.

```
<input id="b1" type="button" onclick="clicar1()" value="Botão 1">
<input id="b2" type="button" onclick="clicar2()" value="Botão 2">
<input id="b3" type="button" onclick="clicar3()" value="Botão 3">

    <script>
        var a = window.document.getElementById('b1')
        var b = window.document.getElementById('b2')
        var c = window.document.getElementById('b3')

        function clicar1() {
            alert('Você clicou no 1º botão')
        }
        function clicar2() {
            alert('Você clicou no 2º botão')
        }
        function clicar3() {
            alert('Você clicou no 3º botão')
        }
    </script>
```

Tentei usar somente uma function, mas não está funcionando, assim:

```
<input id="b1" type="button" onclick="clicar()" value="Botão 1">
<input id="b2" type="button" onclick="clicar()" value="Botão 2">
<input id="b3" type="button" onclick="clicar()" value="Botão 3">

    <script>
        function clicar() {
            
            var a = window.document.getElementById('b1')
            var b = window.document.getElementById('b2')
            var c = window.document.getElementById('b3')

            
            a.alert('Você clicou no 1º botão')
            b.alert('Você clicou no 2º botão')
            c.alert('Você clicou no 3º botão')
        }
    </script>
```

Me parece que o JS não aceita essa sintaxe "a.alert('xyz')". É isso mesmo?

Comment: sim tem, e o seu segundo código está bem próximo disso.. primeiro, passe para a função "clicar" o botão que disparou o evento (pode pegar isso de outra forma, mas assim é mais comum): `onclick="clicar(this)"` na função, pode pegar o valor do botão facilmente `function clicar(botao) {  alert("Voce clicou no botão " + botao.value); }`

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 4):

Quando você associa um evento ao elemento, como fez com o `onclick=`, você está passando uma expressão Javascript no corpo do atributo, ou seja, qualquer coisa que você por lá vai ser interpretado como um script.

Aqui nós temos um exemplo prático de como funcionaria:

```html
<input id="b1" type="button" onclick="alert('Você clicou no botão ' + this.value)" value="Botão 1">
<input id="b2" type="button" onclick="alert('Você clicou no botão ' + this.value)" value="Botão 2">
<input id="b3" type="button" onclick="alert('Você clicou no botão ' + this.value)" value="Botão 3">
```

Claro que isso não é o ideal para fazer, pois está repetindo o código, e não está nem um pouco legível. Podemos reduzir o código acima para:

```js
function alertarBotao(e) {
    alert(e.value);
}
```

```html
<input id="b1" type="button" onclick="alertarBotao(this)" value="Botão 1">
<input id="b2" type="button" onclick="alertarBotao(this)" value="Botão 2">
<input id="b3" type="button" onclick="alertarBotao(this)" value="Botão 3">
```

Ainda não tá legal. E se reduzirmos mais ainda?

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='button']")
elements.
  forEach(e => {
    e.onclick = function() { alert(e.value) }
  })
```

```html
<input id="b1" type="button" value="Botão 1">
<input id="b2" type="button" value="Botão 2">
<input id="b3" type="button" value="Botão 3">
```

De qualquer forma, no seu código, você não associa o evento `onclick` no seu Javascript em lugar nenhum (com excessão nos próprios elementos). Dos exemplos citados, somente o primeiro é o "desagradável", sendo que o segundo ainda também não é muito ideal.

No terceiro caso você tem que dar uma trabalhada com os seletores no `querySelectorAll`. Você pode associar uma classe para os elementos e procurar eles no seu código JS, sem interferir no funcionamento dos outros inputs:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".meu-botao")
elements.
  forEach(e => {
    e.onclick = function() { alert(e.value) }
  })
```

```html
<input class="meu-botao" id="b1" type="button" value="Botão 1">
<input class="meu-botao" id="b2" type="button" value="Botão 2">
<input class="meu-botao" id="b3" type="button" value="Botão 3">
```

Todos os exemplos geram o mesmo resultado, no entanto, somente alguns são "ideais" em termos de manutenção e legibilidade.

Não utilize IDs como seletores quando está trabalhando com um grupo de elementos. Neste caso, é melhor utilizar classes mesmo, porque você pode usar a mesma classe em vários elementos. Você não pode usar o mesmo ID em dois ou mais elementos.

Este último exemplo vai tornar seu código mais organizado do que o precessor. Dá uma lida de como funciona eventos no Javascript [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events).